# How to customize grid ratio in graphview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-graphview

I have used GraphView 3.0 library for my ECG analysis project on Android. I cant find any option to customize grids ratio or you can say step size for x and y axis.

If I need to edit the source code then also let me know how am I supposed to edit it and which function can be edited for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the number of horizontal and vertical labels?
You can set them by using these getGridLabelRenderer methods:

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(int numHorizontalLabels);
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumVerticalLabels(int numVerticalLabels);
```